# Two tasks in a ternary operator - PHP

Tags: php

I want to use two tasks if a ternary operator is true.
as example:
This code:

```php
$bool = false;
if(fnc1($brc)){
$bool = true;
$string = fnc2($brc);
} else {
$string = "unknown";
}
```

To this:

```php
$string = fnc1($brc) ? (fnc2($brc); $bool = true) : "unknown";
```

How is it possible to do more than one task `(fnc2($brc); $bool = true)` if the condition is true? My code doesn't work.

Comment: I think you mean to say ternary operator (not temporary operator)

Comment: @Michael Welch Yes, i mean that ':D
But is it possible or not?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with PHP to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, the **AND** operator works here:

```
$string = fnc1($brc) ? (fnc2($brc) AND $bool = true) : "unknown";
```

With a strong caveat that ternary operators are generally considered bad coding, except for very limited use-cases.  They're fine for single-line, simple comparators, but anything more complex is best written out as in your original example.  You won't be sacrificing any speed, and your code will be infinitely more readable.